# To make PK on unique combination of columns or add a numeric rowID

Tags: mysql, sql

This is more of a design problem then a programming one.

I have a table where I store details about retail products:

```
Name    Barcode    BarcodeFormat  etc...
----------------------------------------
```

`(Name, Barcode, BarcodeFormat)` are three columns will uniquely identify a record in the table (Candidate Key). However, I have other tables that need a FK on this one. So I introduced an `auto_increment` column `itemId` and made that the PK.

My question is - should I have the `PK` as `(itemId, Name, Barcode, BarcodeFormat)` or would it be better to have `PK(itemId)` and `UNIQUE(Name, Barcode, BarcodeFormat)`.

My primary concern is performance in terms of `INSERT` and `SELECT` operations but comments on size are also welcome.

I'm using an `innodb` table with `mysql`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Definitely: PK(itemId) and UNIQUE(Name, Barcode, BarcodeFormat).

- You don't want the hassle of using a multi-part key for all your joins etc
- You may one day have rows *without* barcode values which then won't be unique, so you don't want uniqueness hard-wired into your model (you can easily drop the unique without breaking any relationships etc)
- The constraint on uniqueness is a business-level issue, not a database entity one: You'll always need a key, but you may not always need the business rule of uniqueness

Comment: -1 The choice of 'primary key' is arbitrary. Your last point is particularly baffling: integrity constraints should be the logical representation in the database of the business rules; if they are not then you are doing something seriously wrong!

Comment: @onedaywhen You've missed my point entirely. The unique combination is a *business* centric concept, and therefore **subject to change** at any time as business needs change (as in my perfectly reasonable example of products *without* barcodes, which would break the unique constraint). However, the need for a primary key is *permanent* and therefore may outlive the need for the unique constraint. By separating the two, you build in flexibility and maintainability. By merging the two, you lock database requirements to *current* business requirements (you better hope the business doesn't change)

Comment: Thanks for your further comments but they confirm that I haven't missed your point and my position remains the same. I think the idea that the business rules can change but the database constraints will stay the same is wrong-headed.

Comment: @onedaywhen I'm not trying to be painful here, but you still don't "get it". Let me express it in sql for you. Compare what happens if the business changes such that the unique column combo is no longer required: With the separate key and index, you can `DROP INDEX MY_UNIQUE_INDEX` and everything will still work without having to change *anything* (neither code nor database). But if you use the unique columns *as* the key, everything will break - you'll have to rewrite app code and rework FK relationships in the db, AND you'll have to put in a new key column, which is the solution I have now!

Comment: What happens if the enterprise merges with another who has also keyed products solely on an auto-increment column and there are clashes? If they had both keyed their product on [EAN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Article_Number) or some other industry standard identifier then this problem wouldn't arise. Actually, both these are straw mean arguments because [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_ain't_gonna_need_it), of course.

Comment: You propose simple key=PK, compound key=`UNIQUE`, right? So what is the difference (other than psychological reasons) between what you propose and simple key=`UNIQUE`, compound key= PK? Or `UNIQUE` on both keys? It is arbitrary, meaning there *might* be a reason for choosing one of these PK strategies over the other two but I don't that we have been given nearly enough information here for **you** to say for definite which it should be.

Comment: As for the reasons you have given: your first bullet point: makes no difference which PK strategy is chosen because joins can be made against any columns of compatible data types, regards of whether they comprise a PK, a `UNIQUE` or no key at all. Your second bullet point: if a key needs to be dropped in the future then it makes no difference whether that key is a PK or a `UNIQUE`. Your third bullet point: you've either make a misstatement or you don't understand the fundamentals of data modelling; my earlier comments refer.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have millions of products, or very high throughput requirements it won't make much difference in terms of performance.

My preference is to have a surrogate PK (i.e. the auto increment column, your second option of `PK(itemId)` and `UNIQUE(Name, Barcode, BarcodeFormat)` ) because this is easier to manage if business keys change.

Answer (score 2):

You have **two** candidate keys. We call the three-column compound key the 'natural key' and the `auto_increment` column (in this case) the 'surrogate key'. Both require unique constraints ('unique' in lower case to denote  logical) at the database level.

Optionally, one candidate key may be designated 'primary'. The choice of which key (if any) should get this designation is arbitrary. Beware of anyone giving you definitive advice on this matter!

Answer (score 0):

If you already add an itemId then you should use that as PK and have the other three columns with a UNIQUE.

If you don't have an itemId then you could use the other columns as the PK, but it may become difficult to keep it everywhere. In this case it is not great, because the product should have an id since it is an entity, but if it where just a relationship, then it would be acceptable not to have an id column.